# Bug with jquery validator to compare 2 fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, numeric

I'm meeting a strange thing...

I've a form validated with jquery validator.

I've to compare two fields (only numerics), one has to be greater than the other one.

here's what I do:

```
$.validator.addMethod("oneGreaterThanTwo", function(value, element) {
        return $('#one').val() >= $('#two').val();
    }, "One has to be greater than two");
```

It's working fine until I use numbers greater than 10... 
For example if I put 9 and 4, no problem, If I put 4 and 9 I've my error message "One has to be greater than two" displayed.
But if I put 11 and 4 I'll have the error message displayed until I put a number smaller  that 10....

Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.val()` method returns a string, so even though they'll represent numbers, they'll be compared alphabetically rather than numerically. Use the Javascript `parseInt()` method to convert them to numbers, then compare them.

Comment: parseInt should be use with the radix, so to avoid octal values, like parseInt(value, 10)